# How to Count Number of Data Points?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 200 data points scattered from this loop:

```
import math
plt.figure()

for i in range(200):
    r=random.uniform(-1,1)
    x=random.uniform(-1,1)
    if math.sqrt(x**2+r**2)<1:
        plt.plot(x,r,'r.')
    else:
        plt.plot(x,r,'k.')
redraw()
```

So there will be a number of plots that meets the `if` condition. I want to know the number of those points. What should I do?

Comment: Add a variable and increment this one within the if. (Of course it needs to be created outside of the loop)

Comment: Are you trying to draw a shaded circle?

Comment: @Natecat I think he is approximating **pi** (by monte-carlo sampling). But the code is still incomplete.

Comment: Just one more remark for the future: i don't think you want ```plt.plot()``` here, but ```plt.scatter()```! But you should have observed the chaos already when using ```plt.plot```.

Answer (score 3):

You would just need to increment a counter when the condition is met:

```
import math
plt.figure()

good_samples = 0
for i in range(200):
    r=random.uniform(-1,1)
    x=random.uniform(-1,1)
    if math.sqrt(x**2+r**2)<1:
        plt.plot(x,r,'r.')
        good_samples += 1
    else:
        plt.plot(x,r,'k.')
redraw()
print "Counted {} good samples".format(good_samples)
```